# Apply blur effect over region of texture using directx11

Tags: c#-4.0, directx-11, sharpdx, direct3d11

I'm trying to apply a blur effect on a sub  region of texture shown by white boxes in the image below. The effect is not to be applied to entire texture.

[image]

How could this be achieved ?

Any suggestions ?

Note: Using DirectX11 via SharpDx and C#

Thanks.

Comment: feed the input texture and mask texture (with the boxes) seperately. perform the blur normally, but return the original if the mask isn't white. alternatively, if you are sure you just want boxes, you could adjust the viewport and blur just the portion you want. should be more efficient but less flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I have manged to resolve this without masking as it seemed a bit over complicated for me for now.

I achieved it in Pixelshader by passing a copy of my texture and performing the operation to blur on it.

PixelShader function:

```
float4 PSMainBlurEffect(VertexShaderOutput input) : SV_Target
{
 float fBlurAmont = 0.25;
 float Center = 0.5;
 float4 rgbaValue = 0;
 input.TextureUV -= Center;

 for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
 {
    float scale = 1.0 + fBlurAmont * (i / 14.0);
    rgbaValue += EffectShaderTexture.Sample(EffectSampler, input.TextureUV * scale + Center);
 }

 rgbaValue /= 15;
 return rgbaValue;
}
```

hope its useful for someone else.